# Sorted output in mongodump 3.2.10. How?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodump

I need my mongodump dumps sorted by _id. Previously I used such option for that:

`-q '{$query:{}, $sort:{_id:1}}'`

After upgrading to 3.2.10 the option above started triggering such error

`Failed: error reading collection: unknown top level operator: $query`

How do I achieve the behavior desired in 3.2.10?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--sort) option:

```
--sort '{_id: 1}'
```

Since you're querying for all documents you don't need the `-q` option

Comment: I use mongodump, not mongoexport.